# How to call module in Ruby rspec?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

lib/rspec/core/my_methods.rb

```
module MyLovelyModule

class My_methods

  def my_lovely_method
    save_world

    config.to_prepare do
      Dir.glob(Rails.root + "../simpleRspec/dummy_classes.rb").each do |c|
        require_dependency(c)
      end
  end
end
end
  end
```

lib/simpleRspec/dummy_classes.rb

```
describe MyLovelyModule do

class DummyClasses

  before(:all) do
    @dummy = DummyClasses.new
    @dummy.extend MyLovelyModule
  end

  describe "MyLovelyModule" do
    it "saves the world" do
      expect {
        @dummy.my_lovely_method
      }.to raise_error MeltDownException
    end
  end
end
end
```

I got a error like that:-

```
C:/Users/afzala/RubymineProjects/simpleRspec/lib/simpleRspec/dummy_classes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant MyLovelyModule (NameError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

could anyone please help me out for this issue

Comment: Do you have spec_helper.rb file? Could you show it as well? Is it rails app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your module first. You also need to close the class before you define tests:

```
require 'lib/rspec/core/my_methods.rb'

describe MyLovelyModule do

  class DummyClasses
  end

  before(:all) do
    @dummy = DummyClasses.new
    @dummy.extend MyLovelyModule
  end

  describe "MyLovelyModule" do
    it "saves the world" do
      expect {
        @dummy.my_lovely_method
      }.to raise_error MeltDownException
    end
  end
end
```

Also you will not be able to access `@dummy` in your test. You need to use `before(:each)` in place of `before(:all)`

Comment: I got this error load error....

C:/Users/afzala/RubymineProjects/simpleRspec/lib/simpleRspec/dummy_classes.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- lib/rspec/core/my_methods.rb (LoadError)
 from C:/Users/afzala/RubymineProjects/simpleRspec/lib/simpleRspec/dummy_classes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 from -e:1:in `load'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: As expected. Is it rails app, what is in your load paths? Why do you store your app module in folder called 'rspec'?

Comment: No its a gem Application

Comment: Do you have `spec_helper.rb` file?

Comment: yes , in my spec_helper.rb is gieven below

RSpec.configure do |config|
 # config.before(:each) {print ('before method')}
  config.before(:each)do

  end

  config.after(:each)do

  end

  config.before(:all)do

  end

  config.after(:all)do



  config.before(:suite)do

  end

  config.after(:suite)do

  end end

end

Comment: spec/spec_helper.rb

but its error showing for module ...not for rspec_helper.rb

is any thing installation is require to call module in rspec?

Comment: Your problem is caused by your module not being loaded. It is usually responsibility of spec_helper.rb to load all the needed files.